# linux setting ulimit -n over 1 million

Tags: linux

I'm building an system where I have 1 million open connections open at the same time and some of them reconnect but the thread still waits the deadline.

ulimit -n 999999 is the maximum I can get everything over it will give an error message

`-bash: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted`

How can I set this higher? Why is there even an limit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start by settting this in sysctl:

```
# sysctl -w fs.nr_open=1000000000
```

Then you can set the ulimit

```
# ulimit -n 1000000000
```

This will give you 1000000000 as your ulimit:

```
# ulimit -n           
1000000000
```

1000000000 is the highest I could get it to go.